# Restrict access to a shareable Azure Bastion URL to certain IP addresses

Tags: azure, bastion

I have a Windows VM that I connect to using RDP. For security reasons, I created a Bastion and a shareable URL so that I can give it to the client to connect via Bastion.

The client will connect using the shareable URL (using HTTPS), then choose the RDP protocol and the RDP port. I have restricted the RDP port to allow only certain IP addresses. However, this does not work with the shareable URL.

is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and created a virtual machine and shareable URL like below:

[image]

Created a virtual network with a bastion subnet like below:

[image]

Created bastion and shareable URL like below:

[image]

When I try to restrict access for certain IP addresses using NSG it is restricted successfully like below:

[image]

> **Note**: **Using the Network security group you can restrict access to the RDP protocol. unfortunately in Bastion shareable link, it's not possible to restrict access to the certain IP address**

Peered VNets that have various subscriptions, Peer VNets across the tenants, peered VNets in different regions, and national clouds are currently not supported in shareable URL

***Reference***:

[Create a shareable link for Azure Bastion | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bastion/shareable-link)

Comment: Thank you very much, @imran. I will try your solution and then come back to confirm it for the community.